# Swift Tuple get named parameters

Tags: swift, reflection, enums, tuples

If I have an enum as below:

```
enum TempEnum {    
    case AAA(name:String, age:Int)
    case BBB(country:String)
    case CCC
}
```

I want to be able to for each case generate a dictionary of the associated parameters for each case. I don't want to to a switch!

If I execute this code:

```
let aaa = TempEnum.AAA(name: "bobby", age: 10)
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: aaa)
var labels = [String]()
var values = [Any]()
for (label, value) in mirror.children {
    for (label, value) in Mirror(reflecting: value).children {
        labels.append(label!)
        values.append(value)
    }
}
```

Labels is: `[".0", ".1"]`

Values is: `["bobby", 10]`

Is there any way to retrieve the actual named parameters (if they do exist), so that Labels is `["name", "age"]`

Comment: Probably not. You can reflect a type's property names but probably not a tuple's parameter names.